# Access to local files only work with local HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, local

I would like to access a local file on my computer by clicking on a HTML link

```
<a href="file:///\\mynetworklink\users\myusername\public\mydoc.docx">Link to local file</a>
```

It works very well if I do it from a local HTML file for exemple from :

```
file:///D:/Profiles/myusername/Desktop/testfile.html
```

It even work well by using window.open from Javascript :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('\\\\mynetworklink\\users\\myusername\\public\\mydoc.docx', 'MyWindow');
    </script>
```

But when I do it from my local PHP app with Apache if am not allowed to do so.
Exemple of error while trying with a link tag :

**`Not allowed to load local resource`**

So I heard that Chrome/Firefox/IE are blocking local file access this way for security reasons.

Isn't there any way to make it work without modifying the browsers settings ?
This app is used by a lot of customers and I can't ask everybody to modify there settings.

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: `Isn't there any way to make it work without modifying the browsers settings`.   No..

Comment: Why are you not serving the file from your webserver?

Comment: Have them upload it, or something....

Comment: My best bet would be to turn it into some sort of browser plugin. For Chrome I know a plugin is just a bunch of html and javascript, and you can ask the user for local file access when they install the plugin. Fortunately no other way for a web page to access the local file system...

Comment: @Turnip thanks but It's how the app I'm working on works. The users already have the files on their computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I heard that Chrome/Firefox/IE are blocking local file access this way for security reasons.

Yes

> Isn't there any way to make it work without modifying the browsers settings ?

No. That would make it a pointless security feature.

Comment: After looking a bit more I guess there is no workaround so I will find another solution for this problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Distribute your app as ElectronJS application. This will allow you to get seamless access to your local file system and web features.

Comment: Could php read a local file on an electron app and then display it on the web across multiple devices visibility ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Firefox, with a plugin [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/)

But you also need to download something to install on Windows or Linux following the plugin installation.

I'm still looking for the same solution for IE.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have to configure your Apache to map a resource on your filesystem:

Have a look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html) and probably use the [Alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

httpd.conf

```
Alias "/resources/" "C:/users/myusername/public/resources/"
```

And then use it as below:

```
<a href="/resources/mydoc.docx">Link to local file</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take time to try your solution

Comment: Can anyone told me why is this answer downvoted? Please guys, be constructive. It will help others to make more elaborated and good answers. SO is used to help people about a specifical problem. If an answer is incomplete the user can update it to a more compliant solution.

Comment: I did not downvote but the point is that the files are on the client side and not the server side so it is useless to configure Apache (the server) if the files are not there

Comment: I understand your point of vue if it was the case but, currently @Ga3tan is probably on its development environnement and make tries. So, I imagine he doesn't want to share a resource from its computer to remote people, but when his development will be production ready he will want share resource from the production environment not directly located in the application resources files.

Comment: Read more carefully OP’s question. It is well specified:-)

Comment: Yep, but he talks about Apache... I always try to look the farest ;-)

Comment: My bad, this solution doesn't suit my needs @Okoch